# JSON data do not appear in jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: php, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete, byte-order-mark

I am using jquery ui autocomplete to display filtered data from database. Using the browser's Network utility I confirm that JSON data are returned by the server correctly. But nothing is displayed in the autocomplete menu and looking at the page's source I get "No search results". If I use the response body from the browser's Network utility as source to the jquery ui autocomplete, everything works fine. Any help would be very much appreciated.

The HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 pull-right ui-widget">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="afm" id="autocomplete" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The javascript

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    delay:500,
    minLength:2,
    source: "getAFMJSON.php",
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        location.href="userpage.php?idx=22&q="+ui.item.id;
    }
});
```

The PHP

```
<?php
if (!defined('DP_BASE_DIR')) {
    require_once("base.php");
}
// prevent direct access
$isAjax = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest';
if(!$isAjax) {
    $user_error = 'Access denied - not an AJAX request...';
    trigger_error($user_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

require_once(DP_BASE_DIR."/models/config.php");

// get what user typed in autocomplete input
$term = sanitize(trim($_GET['term']));

$a_json = array();
$a_json_row = array();

$a_json_invalid = array(array("id" => "#", "value" => $term, "label" => "Only letters and digits are permitted..."));
$json_invalid = json_encode($a_json_invalid);

// allow space, any unicode letter and digit, underscore and dash
if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $term) || $term == 0) {
    print $json_invalid;
    exit;
}

global $db;

$sql="SELECT `company_afm`, `company_id` FROM `data_companies` WHERE `company_afm` LIKE '".$db->sql_escape($term)."%'";
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
while($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
    $a_json_row["label"] = $row['company_afm'];
    $a_json_row["id"] = $row['company_id'];
    array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
}

$json = json_encode($a_json);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
print $json;
?>
```

When typing "998" in autocomplete input the JSON response in browser's Network utility is like:  [{"label":"998916950","value":"53"}]

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot, I found out that the problem had to do with the way some editors encode the scripts in UTF-8. In fact, when I edited some scripts with Codeanywhere, the editor allocated [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the very beginning of those scripts. When JSON was generated by those scripts or embedded in scripts encoded in UTF-8 with BOM, it contained the BOM hidden characters, which rendered it invalid and hence useless for JQueryUI Autocomplete. 
I used Notepad++ to convert the JSON generating script and the container scripts to UTF-8 without BOM but I was not cleaning everything. 
Luckily, I found [emrahgunduz/BOMCleaner](https://github.com/emrahgunduz/BomCleaner), which checked all the scripts included in my application and cleaned them from the BOM characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your source is a string called `source: "getAFMJSON.php"`
This needs to be the json value. Since you are doing this using ajax, you should use a function that does the ajax request and returns the results array to you as your source.

Comment: From the [JQueryUI Autocomplete API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source): _When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one_. According to this documentation I provide as source a string containing the relevant url to the PHP file that filters the data from the database. Am I doing something wrong?